# Does vercel clone git repository when deploying it?

Tags: github, vercel

I noticed that in the traffic menu of my repository there is 19 unique cloners in stat graph, but i see only one unique visitor.  So i'm interested does Vercel clone git repository after deploying it?

I searched any related questions, also looked at Vercels docs, but haven't found anything regarding my question.